# The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel(payment gateway)

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest, payment-gateway

I know there are too many questions in the same title.
None of them helped me solve this problem.
So I decided to add the code I wrote.

`Stream dataStream = request.GetRequestStream()` - the problem occurs when this line is reached.

```cs
public ActionResult WebRequest()
{

    string currentIp = "";
    var host = Dns.GetHostEntry(Dns.GetHostName());
    foreach (var ip in host.AddressList)
    {
        if (ip.AddressFamily == AddressFamily.InterNetwork)
        {
            currentIp = ip.ToString();
        }
    }
    ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = true;
    ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls
           | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11
           | SecurityProtocolType.Tls12
           | SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3; 
    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create("https://ecommerce.ufc.ge:18443/ecomm2/MerchantHandler");
    request.Method = "POST";
    string postData = "command=v&amount=<300>&currency=<981>&client_ip_addr=<" + currentIp + ">&description=<desc>&msg_type=SMS";
    byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData);
    request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
    request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;
    string myPath = Server.MapPath("//tbcCert.pem");
    X509Certificate certificate = new X509Certificate(myPath, "----", X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable);
    request.PreAuthenticate = true;
    request.ClientCertificates.Add(certificate);
    Stream dataStream = request.GetRequestStream();
    dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
    dataStream.Close();
    WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
    string StatusDescription = ((HttpWebResponse)response).StatusDescription;
    using (dataStream = response.GetResponseStream())
    {
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);
        string responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();
    }
    response.Close();
    return View();
}
```

here's the error:

> The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel(payment gateway)

Please help me find where my mistake.

Comment: 1. TLS are enabled on respective server or machine ?2. Which framework used ?3. have u tried using "ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = (SecurityProtocolType)3072"

Comment: 1.Actually, I don't know. 2. .Net 4.7.2 3.Yes. but didn' work

Comment: #1. We faced same issue there might be two reasons - a.TLS v1.2 is not enabled on machine/server
b.CIPHERS may be mis match

Comment: I maked TLS 1.2 enabled and changed cipher also. but problem unresolved

Comment: ok. Have tried on any another machine is code working anywhere ?

Comment: Yes. I tried. Still error occurs

Comment: ok .try removing X509 Certificates ..

Comment: I tried, and doesn't work  -_-

Comment: is your system date time properly snyc?

Comment: Yes. But I am not sure that the port 18443 is opened or not. The reason can be that

Comment: ok ,May be . ..i am not sure .

Comment: @BhushanMuttha, Problem still occurs. Do you have any other idea for solution?

Comment: What tls versions are enabled and what ciphers are enabled ..?

Comment: Have u tried ur code on another some low configure machine or higher configure machine ?

Comment: @BhushanMuttha No. I am trying to create cert-store

Comment: okay..i do not know cert-store?What is that exactly ..? Did that solve the issue ?

Comment: The problem was .pem file. I changed it .p12 file and It worked